# How do I fetch a list of objects in grails?

Tags: grails

First of all I am new to grails.

Now I have two domain objects as follows:

```
class ApproverGroup{
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    static hasMany=[corporateHouseUser :CorporateHouseUser]
    static constraints = {
        corporateHouseUser nullable: false
    }
}
```

and

```
class CorporateHouseUser implements Serializable {

    CorporateHouse corporateHouse
    User user

    String personName

    String designation

    TransactionVelocity transactionVelocity

    long groupId

    static constraints = {
        personName nullable: false, blank: false
        transactionVelocity nullable: true
    }

    static auditable = true

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['corporateHouse', 'user']
    }

    String getCreator() {
        return personName
    }
}
```

What I need to do is fetch a list of approver group that belongs to a corporate house along with corporate house users from corporate house id.
In my ApproverGroupService I have created a method that accepts  corporate house id now I want this method to return a list of Approver groups.

I am wondering how to make the following query work?

```
def approverGroupList= ApproverGroup.executeQuery("Select * from ApproverGroup as a where a.corporateHouseUser in (Select * from CorporateHouseUser as u where u.corporateHouse.id = :corporateHouseId)   ",[corporateHouseId:corporateHouseId
        ]);
```

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `createAlias` as it's hibernate specific and doesn't play well with unit tests. If you are joining across a to-many, you need to use `listDistinct` to prevent getting duplicate ApproverGroup entries in the result.

```
ApproverGroup.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    corporateHouseUser {
        eq 'id', corporateHouseId
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on why it's not suitable for unit testing?

Comment: Thank you so much . :)And yes your suggestion totally worked for me. I had to use list distinct at last.

Comment: @Funtik `createAlias()` won't work for a normal unit test as they use a mock persistence layer instead of hibernate and `createAlias()` is a hibernate-specific function. However, as of 2.4, the `DomainClassUnitTestMixin` will allow for testing of code with createAlias. Regardless, I always consider `createAlias` to be a last resort as grails provides many ways to specify the joins without it.

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching it with criteria.

```
def approverGroups = ApproverGroup.withCriteria() {
         createAlias('corporateHouseUser','corporateHouseUser')
         eq('corporateHouseUser.id', corporateHouseId)
    }
```

Comment: All I have to say is Thank you and I totally meant it:).